# Ninject returns specific instance of object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I've been using Ninject like so:

```
ninjectKernel.<IBlogRepository>().To<BlogRepository>();
```

I would like a specific obejct to be returned .
how do I get something like this instead

```
ninjectKernel.<IInvestorRepository>().  // returns this : new BlogRepository(new (new BlogContext(Settings.Default.BlogConnection)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
var singleInstanceOfRepository = new BlogRepository();

ninjectKernel.Bind<IBlogRepository>().ToMethod(context => singleInstanceOfRepository);
```

All the calls to kernel will resolve `IBlogRepository` to `singleInstanceOfRepository`

Comment: Wouldn't you also be able to do                                ninjectKernel.<IBlogRepository>().To<BlogRepository>().InSingletonScope()

Comment: @Jamie - yes, but then Kernel will construct the instance for you. If you want to construct the instance yourself than you need to use provider method. OP was asking about *specific* object, so I assume it's constructed outside of kernel.

Comment: @Jamie how would I use your method to have the BlogRepository new'ed up like:> new BlogRepository(new UnitOfWork(new BlogContext(Settings.Default.BlogConnection)))

Comment: From the example it looks like it wants the  BlogRepotory to be a singleton, that is why I added.  If more needs done then that may be an issue.  I was just trying to add to the discussion.